# scroll a scrollable element using selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am wondering how to scroll on a scrollable element in a web page. I found plenty of answers about how to scroll the whole page (working well) but here it's an inner specific div that is scrollable that I want to scroll to the bottom.

How can I do that with selenium for python?

Comment: have you tried clicking on the div and then send keys `page down` or `control End`?

Comment: @supputuri a random div is not clickable, is it?

Comment: what do you mean by random div, does it have dynamic attribute values?

Comment: Refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838948/scraping-javascript-table-with-a-scroll-using-selenium/59839533#59839533

Comment: @supputuri page down or control end does nothing on that div. In "normal mode" it is only scrollable by the mouse

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and solved it like this:

If this is your HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__element">1</li>
    <li class="list__element">2</li>
    <li class="list__element">3</li>
    <li class="list__element">4</li>
    <li class="list__element">5</li>
    <li class="list__element">6</li>
    <li class="list__element">7</li>
</ul>
```

Select all the child elements of your list like so:

```
list_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'list__element')
```

After that, you can loop over that list and scroll to a specific item.
Note: If your list progressively loads new list elements you need to accoaunt for that.

```
for comment in comments:
        ActionChains(driver)\
        .scroll_to_element(comment)\
        .perform()
        time.sleep(.1)
```